# How to use youtube api 3.0 to upload a video using proxy and python

Tags: python, proxy, youtube-api

There is a Python sample script to upload a video to youtube using Youtube API 3.0 with Oauth authentication at this url "https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video". How to add codes to make it work with a Squid HTTPS proxy (not by setting the proxy environment variable) ?